# iOS uiview and uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Hy

i have two classes uiviewcontroller and uiview. I have one view controller. Inside i have uiview. Inside uiview i have textfield and when i write a text and click done i need to refresh uiviewcontroller.

I tried with this in uiview class:

```
  -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{

      ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [vc viewDidLoad];
}
```

i need refresh the same as you click the button and open viewcontroller.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh" and don't call viewDidLoad after the view has already loaded. Assuming of course that "ViewController" is the class you're already in.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "refresh"

Comment: i have xmlparser and when i clicked button Done i need to refresh this ViewController (same as you push the button and ViewController open). I mean if i create button and open new ViewController and write text in textfield and click Done and when i clicked button Back is worked.

Comment: Well to do this you don't really have to reload the entire contents of a view controller, you could just write up a method that parses again using the new input.

Comment: In the same class i need refreshing or load as if it opened with the button.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean that you want to "refresh" the view, not the view controller.  To do that simply call [self setNeedsDisplay] from the view, or [self.view setNeedsDisplay] from the view controller.  Also make sure that the textfield is a subview of the uiview.  Either do that in the nib file or in code by calling [self addSubview: (textfield here)].

Also, if you want to access the view controller from the view you will need to create an IBOutlet, simply allocating a new ViewController object within the view does not mean that the created view controller controls the view.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I'd recommend going through some ios starter tutorials as well.  Just google that there are a lot.